# How to get underline a list item including the number in an ol?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a leaderboard where users are ranked by wins. Because I am using a custom image for number one on the ordered list I can't seem to use bootstraps' built-in styling options for lists (list-group, list-group-item, etc..). Does anyone have ideas on how to make the whole item have an underline?

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div className="card">
    <div className="card-header">
      Leader Board
    </div>
    <ol start="1" className="firstItem ">
      {mainAccountsList.map(({userName}, i) => { 
        if (i === 0) {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <li className='secondItem px-0'>{userName}</li>
            <span></span>
            </React.Fragment>)
        } else
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <li className='thirdItem'>{userName}</li>
            <span className='listBorder'></span>
          </React.Fragment>
      )})}
    </ol>
  </div>
```

my CSS

```
.firstItem  {
  background-image: url(crown-solid.svg);
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 3% 1%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  
} 

.secondItem  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
} 

.thirdItem {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.crown {
  fill: gold;
}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: This is what it looks like now]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: This is how I want it to look]

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can use Bootstrap's list group with an image. The crown and list numbers could be added as pseudo-elements.

```css
.list-group {
  counter-reset: line-number;
}

.list-group-item {
  counter-increment: line-number;
  text-indent: 24px;
}

.list-group-item:after {
  content: counter(line-number)".";
  text-indent: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-group-item.crowned:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/24);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="list-group m-4">
  <li class="list-group-item crowned">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item crowned">A fourth item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">And a fifth one</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you set `secondItem`  for your list item , it dosent work , you can do it :

```
ol {
 list-style-type: none;
   }
```

and then

```
.firstItem  {
background-image: url(crown-solid.svg);
background-size: 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 3% 1%;
margin-top: 5px;

}
```

OR:
according your second image you can use list grouping in bootstrap this link may can help you [bootstrap listing](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_list_groups.asp)

and about the crown I prefer to use font icon beside this.
you can user for example fontawesom
goodluck bro

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a line add the bottom of each item with css:
`border-bottom: 1px solid grey;`